# Um motivo real para usar o atributo data-* no elemento html?

Tags: html5

Alguém consegue mencionar um único caso real de utilização do atributo data-* (no padrão que sugere a W3C) para o elemento raiz html? Caso não seja possível um motivo real, pelo menos então imaginar uma situação em que seu uso fará pequena ou grande diferença nesse elemento? Obrigada.

Comment: Um exemplo poderia ser encontrado em dropboxs, onde em um menu,  na li do dropbox colocaria (data-target #menu) (se nao me engano) onde menu seria o id da lista de subitens, assim  ao clicar no dropbox ele iria abrir a lista com  id  menu.. Um exemplo disso pode ser achado nos templates sb-admin e sb-admin 2 no startbootstrap.com .. Não coloquei como resposta pois está bastante incompleto, e não posso elaborar uma resposta agora.

Comment: @lvcs entendi quanto ao uso no elemento li, mas e no elemento html? Consegue imaginar uma situação ou identificar um caso real de utilização no elemento html?

Comment: Aperte CTRL+U nessa página e olhe o código fonte, há alguns exemplos.

Comment: @renan esta página do Stackoverflow não possui nenhum atributo data-* em seu elemento html, infelizmente. Será que consegue, mesmo que não contenha exemplos, imaginar uma situação em que data-* pode ser de grande ou pequena utilidade no elemento html?

Comment: Talvez eu não tenha entendido qual é a sua dúvida então. O elemento em que está sua pergunta tem um atributo `data-questionid="118395"`, para que ele serve, só o pessoal do SO pode responder. Chutando (muito longe, talvez) esse valor pode ser usado para apontar qual é o ID da pergunta quando alguém dá um *upvote* ou *downvote*.

Comment: Teria algum motivo para **não usar**?

Comment: @renan acho que vai ajudar, quando falei elemento html estava dizendo "usar data-* como um atributo da tag html", entendeu moço?

Comment: @bfavaretto não sei dizer. Primeiro precisamos saber um real motivo para usar... obrigada!

Comment: Por exemplo, se a página atual apresenta uma notícia, por que não colocar o id da notícia como `data-noticia-id` no elemento raiz, ou no body? Se é um metadado que diz respeito à entidade mais geral que aquele documento html representa, faz sentido colocar na raiz.

Comment: Fazendo o advogado do diabo, eu diria que um bom motivo pra *não usar* é que a tag `html` será parseada antes da meta `charset`, de modo que se o browser tentar abri-lo sem conhecer de antemão sua codificação (por exemplo, se o arquivo for lido do sistema de arquivos local) ele pode ter problemas com caracteres unicode dentro desse atributo. Por essa razão, eu usaria o `body` para guardar atributos "globais" à página, e não o `html`. Agora, algo muito "meta" mesmo, que se aplicasse inclusive ao `head`, talvez tivesse que ir pro `html` mesmo, ainda que com restrições ao conteúdo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando eu utilizava HTML4 e seus "ancestrais" por assim dizer  eu costumava declarar atributos não existentes que de forma sintática não apresentava erro, mas de forma semântica sim.

W3C percebeu que existiam muitos casos nos quais estas declarações deixavam o html poluído e por isto criaram  o data-whatever.

**Exemplo:**

Se você fosse definir um input, geralmente o comportamento dele, por padrão seria apenas ter um valor.
Agora, se você tivesse um menu, e necessita-se definir múltiplos comportamentos, você poderia declara-los assim:

```
data-toggle="true"
data-width="500"
data-height="200"
data-resize="true"
```

Outra coisa bem legal, e que os desenvolvedores antigamente utilizavam `input type='hidden'` para guardar valores de forma que ninguém conseguisse acessa-los, hoje você já poderia coloca-los no mesmo input inserindo o `data-valor`,  estes dois casos são utilizados em vários frameworks e plugins, o que eles trazem em si e mais semântica e confiabilidade em questão de não haver conflito com atributos já existentes.

Compatibilidade [Can I Use data-](http://caniuse.com/#search=Data-)

Comment: No caso `data-valor` posso trocar pra qualquer outro nome, por exemplo aqui `data-outronome`, isso se utiliza usando `javascript` correto?

Comment: @GuilhermeSpinXO não! Se trata de HTML5, leitura recomendada: http://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-os-custom-data-attributes-da-html5/28040

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues entendi seu exemplo com o elemento input, a explicação também é perfeita. Mas consegue definir um caso real de uso no elemento (tag) html, que é a raiz de todas os demais elementos?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Cuidado que a parte sobre compatibilidade do artigo que você indicou não faz muito sentido.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu tinha notado isso,  mas era o único artigo que eu já tinha lido e poderia passar, explica muito do que eu já citei na resposta vou adicionar o can I use

Comment: @IngridFarabulini  Você viu a utilização no html a onde? A única utilização do data- na tag html para mim seria para realizar algum tipo de template.

Comment: Então, é isso que eu quero dizer, não precisa do can I use. O suporte parcial diz respeito à propriedade `dataset` no DOM. Que nem o artigo nem a sua resposta mencionam. Usar atributos com prefixo data- e getAttribute sempre funcionou.

Comment: @bfavaretto  por ele sempre existir agora ele só passou a ser adotado como padrão?

Comment: Não, a recomendação de não criar atributos inexistentes com qualquer nome e sempre usar o prefixo veio no html5. O que estou dizendo é que nunca houve nenhum problema sintático de compatibilidade. O HTML5 acrescentou uma propriedade nos elementos do dom (o dataset), e a tabela do can I use diz respeito a ela.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues até este momento não consegui nenhum exemplo real de uso do atributo data-* em um elemento html. Descobri que era possível utilizar, mas somente através da documentação. É por isso mesmo que minha pergunta é saber um único caso real de uso... pois eu mesma, nunca vi, mas se está ali, disponível para ser usado, é porque alguém deve entender que existe utilidade. Mas qual? Quais? Obrigada!

Comment: @IngridFarabulini É que os data attibutes valem para *qualquer* elemento. Geralmente, criar uma exceção é mais custoso do que não criar. Não existe um caso de uso clássico. Existem casos possíveis, ao menos hipoteticamente, e existe a restrição que o mgibsonbr citou. Não é comum fazer isso, mas também não é proibido.

Comment: @bfavaretto obrigada pela resposta. De fato, é custoso criar restrições. Mas vimos aqui diversos casos para "não utilizar" e somente algumas situações quase inexistentes de real utilidade. Eu nunca vi seu uso em lugar algum. Aí vem a pergunta: será que o custo de restringir tal atributo não acabaria saindo barato em relação ao custo do tempo que milhares de desenvolvedores perderão para aprender algo que está na documentação e que dificilmente será usado? Só responderia que não, caso estivesse claro que seu uso realmente fará diferença e não será somente mais um atributo desnecessário.