# Para que servem os atributos data-target e data-toggle?

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap

Preciso saber, para que servem esses dois atributos ***data-target e data-toggle*** que ficam em *input*s, *button*s e semelhantes no HTML?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Sobre os atributos `data-*`

O HTML5 foi criado pensando na extensibilidade dos dados que precisam ser associados a um determinado elemento mas não necessariamente tem um significado definido.

Atributos `data-*`, habitualmente usados juntamente com o [*framework* Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#js-data-attrs), permitem armazenar informações extras em elementos HTML padrões e semânticos, sem a necessidades de *hacks* como `classList`, atributos fora do padrão, propriedades extras no DOM ou o obsoleto método `setUserData`.

Veja um exemplo abaixo de uso na tag `<article>`:

```
<article
  id="electriccars"
  data-columns="3"
  data-index-number="12314"
  data-parent="cars">
...
</article>
```

Veja que foi criado atributos extras para o elemento em questão e adicionado vários valores a ele, sem a necessidade de fazer algo *estranho* e/ou não semântico.

Leitura recomendada e interessante sobre o assunto [nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118395/um-motivo-real-para-usar-o-atributo-data-no-elemento-html).

### Data Toggle

O `data-toggle` é um atributo de dados do HTML5 que liga automaticamente o **elemento ao tipo correspondente**.

Por exemplo, se você tem um *dropdown*, como [nesta outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15113710):

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Pode perceber que através do uso do `data-toggle` é reafirmado, que o elemento em questão é um *dropdown*.

Alguns outros elementos que são mais *comumente* usados:

```
data-toggle="modal"
data-toggle="collapse"
data-toggle="dropdown"
data-toggle="tab"
```

`data-toggle`, nesses exemplos citados, declaram que o elemento, respectivamente é um [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), *[accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)*, [dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns), e [estrutura de abas](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs).

### Data Target

O `data-target` geralmente utilizado no Bootstrap, está junto aos modais, mas não somente. Pelo próprio nome, subentende-se que irá fazer **referência ao seu alvo, objetivo**. Este atributo deve conter um seletor CSS que aponte para o elemento HTML que irá participar do evento.

Veja um exemplo, utilizando um modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Quando você clicar no botão (e se tudo estiver correto), irá abrir um modal box com o id que seja igual à `myModal`. Sem muito esforço você estará utilizando através do `data-target` mais um dos componentes pré-desenvolvidos JavaScript.

### Adendo

Você pode perceber a diferença quando se compara o código acima, que abrirá um modal com id *myModal*, utilizando os atributos `data-*` e tendo que fazer a codificação manual, veja abaixo:

- Usando atributos data-*

```html
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Novo
</button>
```

- Sem usar os atributos data-*

```
<button id="btnModal">
    Novo
</button>
```

E então na tag *script*, teria que codificar algo semelhante a isso para abrir o modal:

```
$("#btnModal").click(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

---

Temos perguntas respondidas sobre esse assunto no nosso Grande Irmão SO, mais especificamente [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15113710) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944735/what-is-the-data-target-attribute-in-bootstrap-3). Também tem [este artigo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) do MDN, ao qual tirei a maioria das informações.

### Nota sobre os atributos data-*:

O atributo `data-*`, como foi dito é usando com maior frequência juntamente com o [*framework* Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/). Entretanto, é possível utilizar suas funções através de JavaScript somente:

```
var article = document.getElementById('electriccars');
 
article.dataset.columns // "3"
article.dataset.indexNumber // "12314"
article.dataset.parent // "cars"
```

Ou através deste exemplo:

```
var button = document.getElementById('your-button-id');

var cmd = button.getAttribute('data-cmd');
var id = button.getAttribute('data-id');

button.setAttribute('data-cmd', yourNewCmd);
button.setAttribute('data-id', yourNewId);
```

**Mas**, como foi dito pela própria [W3C](http://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes):

> Os atributos de dados personalizados **destinam-se a armazenar dados personalizados privados para a página ou aplicativo, para os quais não há mais atributos ou elementos apropriados**.

Dito isso, é possível compreender que o atributo `data-*` destina-se a armazenar pequenas quantidades de dados invisíveis que **não são cruciais para o usuário e podem se tornar visíveis posteriormente**. Se os dados forem cruciais para o usuário, ele deve ser apresentado de forma visível e mais acessível. Lembrando também que semanticamente falando, existem elementos mais apropriados para casos como esses.

E apesar de ser possível manipular os dados com JavaScript, [não é recomendado](https://intuio.at/blog/dont-use-data-attributes-to-find-html-elements-with-js/).

Comment: Apenas uma nota sobre o uso da palavra: [**«depreciado» em inglês é «depreciated» e não «deprecated». A palavra «deprecated» que seria a correta para se referir a isto seria traduzida como «obsoleto», «desaprovado», «censurado»**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178138/3635)

Comment: Creio que a resposta está falando de bootstrap ou algum framework similar, não? afinal, a função do "data-*" é dependente da aplicação. não tem significado especificado para o navegador (o que seria a parte mais importante da resposta). Corrija-me se eu estiver errado, não parei pra revisar com base técnica.

Answer (score 10):

Como muito bem explicado pelo colega UzumakiArtanis, os atributos `data-*` são criados para adicionarmos mais informações relacionadas ao elemento, e isto é muito utilizado em diversas bibliotecas e *plugins*.

No caso de `data-target` e `data-toggle`, isso também acontece. Muito provavelmente você está falando do *plugin* para diálogos modal do Bootstrap. Este *plugin* é que define qual o significado desses atributos, não a especificação HTML5.

O bootstrap definiu que o *plugin* Modal vai localizar todos os `data-toggle="modal"` e trabalhar com este elemento para poder abrir a janela de diálogo, que é ligada a ele pelo atributo `data-target`.

**Fontes**:

- [Bootstrap Modal](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)
- [Get Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/)