# dúvida select com modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Estou tendo problemas para executar uma ação no meu site. Tenho um *select* com algumas opções, preciso selecionar uma das opções e dar *submit* em um botão, ao fazer isso teria que abrir um modal (popup)?

Ou seja, selecionei a opção, cliquei no botão "enviar" e nisso abre o modal específico da opção selecionada.

Estou fazendo isso no *WordPress* e usando o Bbootstrap

**HTML do modal:**

```html
<div id="sintomas">
 <div class="options">
  <select class="custom-select custom-sintomas">
   <option selected>Selecione um sintoma aparente</option>
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
   <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode detectar com JQuery o valor do option quando você seleciona uma das opções e abrir o modal especifico da seguinte forma

```
        $('select').change(function () {

           $('[id^="modal"]').modal('hide');

           var qualModal = "#modal"+$(this).val();

           $(qualModal).modal('show');

        });
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
     $('select').change(function () {
     
        $('[id^="modal"]').modal('hide');
        
        var qualModal = "#modal"+$(this).val();

        $(qualModal).modal('show');

     });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 


    <div id="sintomas">
     <div class="options">
      <select class="custom-select custom-sintomas">
       <option selected>Selecione um sintoma aparente</option>
       <option value="1">One</option>
       <option value="2">Two</option>
       <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal 1-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title 111111</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          1111111111
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal 2-->

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title 222222</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            2222222222
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

     <!-- Modal 3-->

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title 333333</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            3333333333
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
             
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

### Com botão abrindo modal especifico

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function () {

       $('[id^="modal"]').modal('hide');

       var targetBotao = "#modal"+$(this).val();

       $('#testButton').attr('data-target',targetBotao);

    });
});
```

> Quando você selecionar um option do select o `data-target` do botão irá assumir o valor da variável `targetBotao` que será composto pela string `#modal` concatenado pelo `value` do option selecionado. Dessa forma quando clicado abrirá o modal especifico.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('select').change(function () {
    
    $('[id^="modal"]').modal('hide');
    
    var targetBotao = "#modal"+$(this).val();
 
    $('#testButton').attr('data-target',targetBotao);

 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 


<div id="sintomas">
 <div class="options">
  <select class="custom-select custom-sintomas">
   <option selected>Selecione um sintoma aparente</option>
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
   <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="testButton" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 1-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title 111111</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      1111111111
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 2-->

<div class="modal fade" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title 222222</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        2222222222
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 <!-- Modal 3-->

<div class="modal fade" id="modal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title 333333</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        3333333333
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
         
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Sobre os atributos data-*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227604/para-que-servem-os-atributos-data-target-e-data-toggle)

Comment: sim, eu consegui fazer dessa forma, só que não é o que eu preciso 100%, já pesquisei muito e não consegui fazer a função, eu preciso que o modal só se eu selecionar uma opção e clicar em um botão, no exemplo acima o modal já aparece quando seleciona a opção.
no caso seria assim , por exemplo:
eu seleciono a option 1 e clico em um botão, ai o modal 1 é mostrado.
se eu seleciono a option 2 e clico em um botão, o modal 2 é mostrado.
o grande problema é que eu preciso de um botão para confirmar o processo.

Comment: Esse botão além de mostrar o modal o que mais iria fazer?

Comment: nada, ele só tem que abrir o modal correto, porque eu vou precisar usar uns 10 modelos de modal diferente, ai no caso, eu selecionava a opção 1, clicava no botão e ele me mostrava o modal respectivo da opção 1

Comment: Nesse caso o botão só vai fazer o usuário gastar mais um clique!

Comment: sim, eu entendo, por mim também faria desta forma, eu trabalho em uma agência de comunicação, e o cliente quer desta maneira :(, se puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato!

Comment: @MiguelCampos resposta editada com versão para botão. Não deixe de ler esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Leo, por favor, estou com um outro problema, o script por algum motivo não quer funcionar, já adicionei o jquery e o bootstrap, aparentemente os dois estão funcionando, testei até a função do modal somente no botão que peguei direto no site do bootstrap e funcionou.

Comment: @MiguelCampos, acredito que seja devido a colocação do script na página. Ou você coloca ele no final da página ou coloca ele dentro de `$( document ).ready(function() {` o script .... `});` conforme resposta editada

Comment: muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente agora!